# Filter a dynamic angular checkbox

Tags: angular

I'm trying to work on a checkbox with dynamic data.

I get the data from this API function:

```
dataAPI() {
    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
```

and then I pass using this function:

```
passData() {
    this.dataAPI().subscribe((res) => {
      this.holder = res.data;
      console.log(res);

      this.addCheckboxesToForm();
    });
  }
```

I store data from API to 'holder' but my problem is the filtering does not work.

```
applyFilter(event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    this.holder.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

This is my stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yakni3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: your `holder` variable is only an array of object. if you makes `this.holder.filter=...` the only is add a property to the object. It's looks like you copy some code from a Material dataTable. If you want to filter an array of object you should to have two variables (e.g. holder and holderFiltred and use some like `this.holderFiltered=this.holder.filter(x=>x.email.toLowerCase().contains(filterValue)`

Comment: @Eliseo I have made changes with what you said. I made a function with a parameter with argument depending on if the user search or not. But I have some trouble with the function filter itself. This is my update stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yakni3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we has a FormArray and a filter. We can iterate over the formArray.controls (and use a function to know if the "email" is included in the filtered array) or create a filtered array that know the index of the formArray.

I choose the second approach because it's better always avoid use a complex function in the .html. So we are going to change a bit the applyFilter function

```
  applyFilter(event:any) {
    const filterValue = event?event.target.value.toLoweCase():'';

    this.holderFiltered = this.holder
      .map((x, index) => ({
        index: index,
        value: x,
      }))
      .filter((y: any) => y.value.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));

  }
```

See that first we "map" the array to create an array with two properties: index (the index of the element) and value (the element itself). After we filter the value. We take account that if we don't pass to the function the "event" argument, the filteredValue is `''`

As we want to use the input as `[formControl]="what-ever"` we need a function that return the FormControl in an index

```
  getOrder(index) {
    return this.ordersFormArray.at(index) as FormControl;
  }
```

Now out .html becomes like

```
  <label *ngFor="let hold of holderFiltered; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="getOrder(hold.index)" />
    {{ hold.value.email }}
  </label>
```

Well, the last is not forget give value to holderFiltered when the data is received

```
this.dataAPI().subscribe((res) => {
  this.holder = res.data;
  this.addCheckboxesToForm(this.holder);
  this.applyFilter(null)
});
```

You can see in your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yc3qyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Sorry, in the comment I wrote use of 'contains', and is 'include'

NOTE2: you can use directly the formArray. I want to say without use a FormGroup and inside a FormArray

Answer (score 0):

first in `applyFilter` function use includes instead of contain it'll be like :-

```
  this.holderFiltered = this.holder.filter((x) =>
      x.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
```

then in `addCheckboxesToForm` function you have to clear your form array first like this : -

```
this.ordersFormArray.clear();

  private addCheckboxesToForm(dataHold: any) {
    this.ordersFormArray.clear();
    dataHold.forEach(() => this.ordersFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
  }
```